# Docker-compose postgres table not showing up on Navicat

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4, navicat, laradock

I have a docker running and everything is okay, my app running well.

but, I can't show my table on Navicat. even though it's showed up on pgAdmin.

[image]

[image]

I've no idea what to do.

**Edit**

I can do a query, but the table still not showing.
[image]

Comment: did you solve this problem already?